# PySide zoom in/zoom out with scaling

Tags: python, drawing

I am working on a little personal project to entertain myself while I'm at work. It is a little drawing application written in Python. The canvas set to scale within the GUI so that it does not exceed the boundaries of the GUI causing it to expand.

What I'd like to accomplish is to maintain the default scaling while being able to manually scale the canvas as needed such that if someone wanted to zoom in to add detail to a drawing they could do so. I would also like to do the inverse or zoom out. I think it would make sense to zoom in or out by 10% increments per instance.

To control scaling I'd like to use Ctrl+ and Ctrl-.

I've tried a few things like defining zoom in/zoom out, trying to connect it to the self.scaling_factor, but to no avail, it doesn't work. I was able to make it work very brokenly once, but it didn't seem like that was going in the right direction either. The canvas basically able to rescale the canvas, expand the GUI, and then break the whole program.

Here is the code for reference:

```
class Canvas(QMainWindow):
     def __init__(self, canvas_width, canvas_height):
        super(Canvas, self).__init__()

        # Canvas information
        self.setWindowTitle("Assam 2023")

        # Max canvas size
        max_size = QSize(1920, 1080)

        # Calc
        ratio = min(canvas_width / max_size.width(), canvas_height / max_size.height())
        self.scaling_factor = 0.5 if ratio <= 1 else 0.5 / ratio

        # Canvas window size policy
        self.canvas_widget = QWidget()
        self.canvas_widget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        # Canvas gui creation
        screen = QApplication.primaryScreen()
        rect = screen.availableGeometry()
        self.setGeometry(rect)

        # Canvas
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt.white))
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        self.view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.view.setFixedSize(canvas_width * self.scaling_factor, canvas_height * self.scaling_factor)
        self.view.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.view.setTransform(QTransform().scale(self.scaling_factor, self.scaling_factor))

        # More canvas setup
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.view, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.canvas_widget.setLayout(layout)

        # Add canvas widget to main window
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas_widget)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Gui information
        self.setWindowTitle("New Canvas")
        self.setFixedSize(300, 250)

        # Add a combo box for selecting the unit of measurement
        unit_label = QLabel("Unit:")
        self.unit_combobox = QComboBox()
        self.unit_combobox.addItems(["Pixels", "Inches", "Centimeters"])
        self.unit_combobox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.update_unit_label)

        # Add labels and text boxes for entering width and height
        width_label = QLabel("Width:")
        self.width_textbox = QLineEdit() 
        height_label = QLabel("Height:")
        self.height_textbox = QLineEdit()
        # Add a label for displaying the selected unit of measurement
        self.unit__display_label = QLabel("Pixels")

        # Add a text box for entering the PPI value
        self.ppi_label = QLabel("PPI:")
        self.ppi_textbox = QLineEdit()
        self.ppi_textbox.setEnabled(False)

        # Add a button for creating the canvas
        open_canvas = QPushButton("Open")
        create_canvas_button = QPushButton("Create Canvas")

        # Add a layout to organize the widgets
        form_layout = QFormLayout()
        form_layout.addRow(unit_label, self.unit_combobox)
        form_layout.addRow(self.ppi_label, self.ppi_textbox)
        form_layout.addRow(width_label, self.width_textbox)
        form_layout.addRow(height_label, self.height_textbox)
        form_layout.addRow(QLabel(""), self.unit__display_label)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(form_layout)
        layout.addWidget(create_canvas_button)
        layout.addWidget(open_canvas)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # Connect the button click to create_canvas function
        open_canvas.clicked.connect(self.open_canvas)
        create_canvas_button.clicked.connect(self.create_canvas)

    def update_unit_label(self, text):
        self.unit__display_label.setText(text)
        if text == "Pixels":
            self.ppi_textbox.setEnabled(False)
            self.ppi_label.setText("PPI:")
        elif text == "Inches":
            self.ppi_textbox.setEnabled(True)
            self.ppi_label.setText("PPI:")
        elif text == "Centimeters":
            self.ppi_textbox.setEnabled(True)
            self.ppi_label.setText("PPcm:")
        
    def open_canvas(self):    
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        #options |=  QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Canvas", "", "Images (*.jpg)", options=options)
        if file_name:
            with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
                canvas_size = file.read().split(",")
            if len(canvas_size) == 2:
                canvas_width, canvas_height = canvas_size
                self.canvas = Canvas(int(canvas_width), int(canvas_height))
                self.canvas.show()    
    
    def create_canvas(self):
        # Get the selected unit from the combo box
        selected_unit = self.unit_combobox.currentText()

        # Get the values of width and height from the text boxes
        width = int(self.width_textbox.text())
        height = int(self.height_textbox.text())

        # Calculate the canvas size based on the selected unit of measurement
        if selected_unit == "Pixels":
            canvas_width = width
            canvas_height = height
        elif selected_unit == "Inches":
            ppi = int(self.ppi_textbox.text()) if self.ppi_textbox.text() else 96 # default PPI value is 96
            canvas_width = width * ppi
            canvas_height = height * ppi
        elif selected_unit == "Centimeters":
            ppi = int(self.ppi_textbox.text()) if self.ppi_textbox.text() else 96 # default PPI value is 96
            canvas_width = width * 37.8 * ppi / 96
            canvas_height = height * 37.8 * ppi / 96

        # Create a new canvas with the specified dimensions
        self.canvas = Canvas(canvas_width, canvas_height)
        self.canvas.show()

        # Close the new canvas window
        self.close()
```